# Redirect from uppercase anchor urls to lowercase

Tags: redirect, anchor, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect all URLs from upper case to lower case via 301.

I had a table of contents which created a lot of URLs like this:
domain.com/directory/title/#This-Is-The-Anchor.

I want to redirect these to
domain.com/directory/title/#this-is-the-anchor

Online I found a few solutions about htaccess, however the solutions are already from ~2010. Which solution is preferable?

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  In other words, please provide the code you tried from one of those solutions you found and explain what didn't work in your case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.